# How to input text file to api in R

Tags: r, file-io

I want to use this api:

```
http(s)://lindat.mff.cuni.cz/services/morphodita/api/
```

with the method "tag". It will tag and lemmatize my text input. It has worked fine with a text string (see below), but I need to send an entire file to the API.

Just to show that string as input works fine:

```
    method <- "tag"
    lemmatized_text <- RCurl::getForm(paste#
    ("http://lindat.mff.cuni.cz/services/morphodita/api/", method, sep = ""),
    .params = list(data = "Peter likes cakes. John likes lollypops.",#
    output = "json", model = "english-morphium-wsj-140407-no_negation"), #
method = method)
```

This is the - correct - result:

```
[1] "{\n \"model\": \"english-morphium-wsj-140407-no_negation\",\n 
\"acknowledgements\": [\n  \"http://ufal.mff.cuni.cz
/morphodita#morphodita_acknowledgements\",\n  \"http://ufal.mff.cuni.cz
/morphodita/users-manual#english-morphium-wsj_acknowledgements\"\n ],\n
\"result\": [[{\"token\":\"Peter\",\"lemma\":\"Peter\",\"tag\":\"NNP
\",\"space\":\" \"},{\"token\":\"likes\",\"lemma\":\"like\",\"tag\":\"VBZ
\",\"space\":\" \"},{\"token\":\"cakes\",\"lemma\":\"cake\",\"tag\":\"NNS

[truncated by me]
```

However, replacing a string with a vector with elements corresponding to lines of a text file does not work, since the API requires a string on input. Only one, by default the first, vector element would be processed:

```
    method <- "tag"
    mydata <- c("cakes.", "lollypops")
    lemmatized_text <- RCurl::getForm(paste("http://lindat.mff.cuni.cz
    /services/morphodita/api/", method, sep = ""), 
    .params = list(data = mydata, output = "json", 
    model = "english-morphium-wsj-140407-no_negation"))

[1] "{\n \"model\": \"english-morphium-wsj-140407-no_negation\",\n 
      [truncated by me]
    \"result\": [[{\"token\":\"cakes\",\"lemma\":\"cake\",\"tag\":\"NNS
     \"},{\"token\":\".\",\"lemma\":\".\",\"tag\":\".\"}]]\n}\n"
```

This issue can be alleviated with `sapply` and a function calling that API on each element of the vector at the same time, but each element of the resulting vector contains a separate json document. To parse it, I need the entire data to be one single json document, though.

Eventually I tried `textConnection`, but it returns an erroneous output:

```
    mydata <- c("cakes.", "lollypops")
    mycon <- textConnection(mydata, encoding = "UTF-8")
    lemmatized_text <- RCurl::getForm(paste#
    ("http://lindat.mff.cuni.cz/services/morphodita/api/", method,# 
    sep = ""), .params = list(data = mycon, output = "json",# 
    model = "english-morphium-wsj-140407-no_negation"))  

[1] "{\n \"model\": \"english-morphium-wsj-140407-no_negation\",\n 
\"acknowledgements\": [\n  \"http://ufal.mff.cuni.cz
/morphodita#morphodita_acknowledgements\",\n  \"http://ufal.mff.cuni.cz
/morphodita/users-manual#english-morphium-wsj_acknowledgements\"\n ],\n 
\"result\": [[{\"token\":\"5\",\"lemma\":\"5\",\"tag\":\"CD\"}]]\n}\n"
attr(,"Content-Type")
```

I should probably also say that I have already tried to paste and collapse the vector into one single element, but that is very fragile. It works with dummy data but not with larger files and never with Czech files (although UTF-8 encoded). The API strictly requires UTF-8-encoded data. I therefore suspect encoding issues. I have tried this file:

```
    mydata <- RCurl::getURI("https://ia902606.us.archive.org/4/items/maidmarian00966gut/maidm10.txt", .opts =  list(.encoding = "UTF-8"))
```

and it said

```
Error: Bad Request
```

but when I only used a few lines, it suddenly worked. I also made a local copy of the file where I changed the newlines from MacIntosh to Windows. Maybe this helped a bit, but it was definitely not sufficient.

Eventually I should add that I work on Windows 8 Professional, running R-3.2.4 64bit, with RStudio Version 0.99.879.

Answer (score 0):

I should have used `RCurl::postForm` instead of `RCurl::getForm`, with all other arguments remaining the same. The `postForm` function can not only be used to write files on the server, as I had wrongly believed. *It does not impose strict limits on the size of the data to be processed*, since, with `postForm` the data do not become part of the URL, unlike with `getForm`.

This is my convenience function (requires RCurl, stringi, stringr, magrittr):

```
    process_w_morphodita <- function(method, data, output = "json", model  
    = "czech-morfflex-pdt-161115", guesser = "yes",...){  
    # for formally optional but very important argument-value pairs see
    MorphoDiTa REST API reference at 
    # http://lindat.mff.cuni.cz/services/morphodita/api-reference.php 
    pokus <- RCurl::postForm(paste("http://lindat.mff.cuni.cz/services
    /morphodita/api/", method, sep = ""), .params = list(data = 
    stringi::stri_enc_toutf8(data), output = output, model = model,
    guesser = guesser,...))
   if (output == "vertical") {
      pokus <- pokus %>% stringr::str_trim(side = "both") %>%   
      stringr::str_conv("UTF-8") %>% stringr::str_replace_all(pattern = 
      "\\\\t", replacement = "\t") %>% stringr::str_replace_all(pattern =
      "\\\\n", replacement = "\n") # look for four backslashes, replace 
      with one backslash to get vertical format in text file
      }
  return(pokus)
  }
```